# Error trying to parse argument with a delimiter into an array in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to take inputs using commandline argument. The argument will be separated by a delimiter ';'. I wrote the following shell script for it:

```
arg=$1
echo "Input : $arg"
if [ arg != "" ]; then
    echo "input(s) given...."
    IFS=';' read -d '' -ra ADDR <<<"$arg"
    echo "${ADDR[0]}"
    echo "${ADDR[1]}"
    echo "${ADDR[2]}"
    for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
        echo "$i"
    done
fi
```

With the above, when I run as `./script.sh a;b;c` the following is what is happening:

(Expected : ADDR[0] = a, ADDR[1] = b, addr[2] = c,)
Output :

```
$ ./script.sh a;b;c


Input : a

input(s) given....
a



a

b: command not found
c: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong here? Clearly, `$1` is not a;b;c but just `a`. How do I make it work according to my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`;` is the character for separating commands.

Try: `./script.sh 'a;b;c'`

Comment: Is there a work around for this? Can I not do without ' '?

Comment: I can only think of one other separator to use. For example `:`

Comment: Okay, I'll have to change the delimiter then.